# Pointer arithmetic in C adding and subtracting wrong

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Right now I have a code thatdoes pointer arithmetic like this

```
var1 + sizeof(structA)
```

Var1 is a pointer, and structA is a struct with sizeOf 4 bytes. The problem is that when I do this, the address gets shifted down 16 bytes instead of 4. I found that the problem is because in C even though I typed that it's actually

```
var1 + sizeof(structA) * sizeof(int)
```

as int is the return of sizeof. Is there a way I can fix this? 
For a similar problem, I'm doing

```
var1 - sizeof(structA)
```

But instead of shifting up 16 bytes, it shifts up 32 bytes, so 0x10000032 becomes 0x10000000.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the full type of `var1`? (I'm going to guess `structA *`).

Comment: "so 0x10000032 becomes 0x10000000" - this is a 50-byte change.

Comment: If you want to fix it, you definitely need to understand [the pointer arithmetics in C](https://www.google.com/#q=pointer%20arithmetics%20in%20c) first.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped. It's 0x10000004 becoming 0x0FFFFFFC, so 8 byte change. @PhilipKendall Yes it's structA *

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `var1 + sizeof(structA)` use `var1 + 1`

Pointer arithmetic is defined such that the numerical value of the pointer is incremented (and decremented) by the size of the object type.

Hence, the numerical value of `var1+1` is the same as the numerical value of `var1` + `sizeof(*var1)`.

The numerical value of `var1-1` is the same as the numerical value of `var1` - `sizeof(*var1)`.

**Sample program**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct FiftyBytes
{
   char d[50];
};

struct FortyBytes
{
   char d[40];
};

void test1()
{
   struct FiftyBytes a[2];
   struct FiftyBytes* var1 = a;
   struct FiftyBytes* var2 = var1 + 1;
   printf("var1: %p, var2: %p\n", var1, var2);

   struct FiftyBytes* var3 = &a[1];
   struct FiftyBytes* var4 = var3 - 1;
   printf("var3: %p, var4: %p\n", var3, var4);
}

void test2()
{
   struct FortyBytes a[2];
   struct FortyBytes* var1 = a;
   struct FortyBytes* var2 = var1 + 1;
   printf("var1: %p, var2: %p\n", var1, var2);

   struct FortyBytes* var3 = &a[1];
   struct FortyBytes* var4 = var3 - 1;
   printf("var3: %p, var4: %p\n", var3, var4);
}

int main()
{
   test1();
   test2();
}
```

**Output**

```
var1: 0x22ca50, var2: 0x22ca82
var3: 0x22ca82, var4: 0x22ca50
var1: 0x22ca70, var2: 0x22ca98
var3: 0x22ca98, var4: 0x22ca70
```

If you check the differences in the pointer values, you'll notice that:

```
0x22ca82 - 0x22ca50 = 0x32 = 50
0x22ca98 - 0x22ca70 = 0x28 = 40
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but I want to keep it sizeof(structA) just in case in the future the structA size increase/decrease, then my code would still work

Comment: And also, how would I do subtraction? I tested it and 10000004 (var1) - 1 returns 0ffffffc, which means it subtracted 32 S:

Comment: @MoJo It won't matter if you increase the size of structA. When you recompile it, it will increment the address by the correct number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
((char*)var1) + sizeof(structA)
```

Comment: Ugh. Why would anyone want to do that??

Comment: @void_ptr sometimes you've read a file header from disk, for example, and you want to skip over it.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes this is exactly why I'm doing this. I need it to skip over the header of a block of memory to go to the memory block (it's for a mem allocation program I'm working on)

Comment: @MarkRansom - I would argue that putting something that is _not_ an array of `structA` into a memory block pointed to by `structA *var1` is conceptually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In C the expression `ptr + ival`, where `ptr` is a `T*` pointer to the n-th item of an array of type `T[]` and `ival` is of integral type, is *by definition* a pointer to the `(n+ival)`-th item of the same array (provided the resulting index falls inside the array length). So for

```
char  b[7];
char *pb = &b[2];
char *qb = pb+3;
```

pointer `qb` points at `b[5]`, while for

```
long  l[7];
long *pl = &l[2];
long *ql = pl+3;
```

pointer `ql` points at `l[5]`. Compiler automatically recognizes the actual size of `byte` of `long` items of an array, based on the pointer type.

Hence adding an integer value to a pointer corresponds to moving the pointer by the indicated *number of elements* (with the size of an element known by the type of a pointer), not by the given number of bytes in memory.
Similary, subtracting an integer value from a pointer value yields a pointer shifted a given *number of items* (not bytes) back.